# Total count of items in child collections in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

How to get count of items in the child collection ?

```
class company
{
    public ObservableCollection<employee> employees { get; set; }
}

class employee
{
}
```

Lets say there are 5 companies and each company has 7 employees in its collection. How to get the count of total employees (=35)?

Comment: Have you tried *anything* yet? (It helps if your sample code uses idiomatic naming conventions, by the way.)

Comment: Just For-Each and having count variable there (lots of code to write!)

Comment: Not really... About 6 lines, I reckon.

Comment: Compared to 1 line as with your answer below, it is a lot.

Comment: Even so, it would have been worth you showing what you *can* do, and asking whether there was anything simpler - that way you don't look like you're just asking for others to do your work for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `SelectMany`

```
Companies.SelectMany(x => x.employees).Count()
```

Comment: Or `companies.Sum(c => c.Employees.Count)` - there's no need to actually iterate over them all.

Comment: Is the Sum more efficient than SelectMany here?

Comment: Yes, since `ObservableCollection` knows its own size without the need to iterate over it, @JonSkeet solution would be more efficient.